# referencing imported js code to imported elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

**index.php**

```
<img class='imga' src='some_src' alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='some_src' alt='img'>

<?php include('anima.php');?>
```

**anima.php**

```
<img class='imga ' src='some_src' alt='img'>
<img class='imga' src='some_src' alt='img'>

<button>CLICK</button>

<script>
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.imga').hide();
}
</script>
```

Click on `button` hides all (4) images.

Is there a way to tell that imported `js` code is referencing only to elements in the same, imported file?

In the above case it should hide only the last two images.

And that's a simplified version of the problem.

In reality many php files are included, having its own `imga` and `js` code.

Of course I can re-class images and retargeting js code manually, but it's a huge job.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you could have each include's output be wrapped in a div with a different id. Then reference that ID in the jQuery. Because once its outputted to the browser, the browser doesn't care if you included it from 1 or 1 million PHP files, at the end of the day its all HTML.

Then in order to automate the editing of the includes to wrap the output, use PHP to scan the directory for the includes. Have it open the file, prepend the div and append the end div and have it overwrite the file. That way with a few minutes of work, all of the includes can be updated.

EDIT: example

Below is a basic example that you will want to modify for your needs. It scans a folder, opens a file, wraps the content in a div with the ID of the file name minus **.php** and overwrites that file with the new contents.

```
<?php
$dir = "testfiles/";
    $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach($files as $file){
            if(strlen($file) > 4){
                file_put_contents($dir . $file,"<div id='" . str_replace(".php","",$file) . "'>" . file_get_contents($dir . $file) . "</div>") ;
            }
    }
?>
```

Depending on how your include works, you might instead want to add echo to the beginning and end of it instead of a plain output. I wasn't sure on how your includes work and I have seen it done many ways.

Comment: excuse me, can't understand fully the second part. Could you write an example, pls

Answer (score 1):

As far you are including the first page in the other, which would mean both are on the same page, renaming the classes is the only way out here.